# pass json file to testNG Data Provider

Tags: testng, rest-assured, rest-assured-jsonpath

How can I pass Json File which contains a json array to TestNG data Provider and use it in my test to parametrize my test cases. 
this is a Json file which I want to pass to TestNG test cases as Data Provider :

```
 {"TestList":[{
      "display_name":"test1",
      "type":"testlist",
      "author":null,
      "body":
        {
          "description":"test1 tl",
          "type":"GENERIC"
        },
      "perm_read":"all",
      "perm_write":"all",
      },
        {
          "display_name":"test2",
          "type":"testlist",
          "author":null,
          "body":
          {
            "description":"test2 tl",
            "type":"GENERIC"
          },
          "perm_read":"all",
          "perm_write":"all",
        },
        {
          "display_name":"test3",
          "type":"testlist",
          "author":null,
          "body":
          {
            "description":"test3 tl",
            "type":"GENERIC"
          },
          "perm_read":"all",
          "perm_write":"all",
        }
    ]}
```

Here are the test and Data Provider in which I am trying to use Json file :

```
    @Test(dataProvider = "body")
        public void AddTestGroup() throws InterruptedException{
           System.out.println("Parsed json ===" + TestData);

        }
 @DataProvider(name = "body")
    public Object[][] body() throws IOException{
        JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
        JSONObject jsonObject = null;
        JSONArray json_array = null;
        try {
            Object obj = parser.parse(new FileReader("./TestDataFile.json"));
            jsonObject = (JSONObject) obj;
            json_array = (JSONArray) jsonObject.get("TestList");

        }catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return json_array;
    }
```

how can I do it so that json_array can have

```
json_Array[0] = {
  "display_name":"test1",
  "type":"testlist",
  "author":null,
  "body":
    {
      "description":"test1 tl",
      "type":"GENERIC"
    },
  "perm_read":"all",
  "perm_write":"all",
  }
```

and

```
jason_array[1] =  {
      "display_name":"test2",
      "type":"testlist",
      "author":null,
      "body":
      {
        "description":"test2 tl",
        "type":"GENERIC"
      },
      "perm_read":"all",
      "perm_write":"all",
    },
```

and so on and can be used in my test cases.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try using the below code. it worked when i used ur json.

```
    public class NewTest {
        @DataProvider(name = "JsonParser")

        public static Object[] credentials() {

            Object[] data = null;
// I saved the Json in a file.
            String filename = "YourFilePath";
            try {
                JsonObject jObject = new JsonParser().parse(new FileReader(new File(filename))).getAsJsonObject();
                JsonArray jArray = jObject.getAsJsonArray("TestList");
                data = new Object[jArray.size()];
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.size(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(jArray.get(i));
                    data[i] = jArray.get(i);
                }

            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
            return data;

        }

        // Here we are calling the Data Provider object with its Name

        @Test(dataProvider = "JsonParser")

        public void test(Object arrays) {

            System.out.println("From test class" + arrays);

        }
```

Comment: How to get only value like display_name inside @Test method using Object arrays?

Answer (score 3):

You can use `JsonPath` to make your code even easier.

```
    @DataProvider(name = "body")
    public Object[] body() throws IOException{
        JsonPath path = JsonPath.from(new File("./TestDataFile.json"));
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> maps = path.getList("TestList");
        Object[] hashMaps = maps.toArray();
        return hashMaps;
    }
```

The above code will parse your JSON Array into List of `HashMap`s. Each of Map is the set of data you want to use.

Then, in your test, you need to declare that method annotated with `@Test` accepts `HashMap<String, Object>` as an argument, like this:

```
    @Test(dataProvider = "body")
    public void test(HashMap<String, Object> map)
    {
        System.out.println(map.get("display_name"));
    }
```

In order to get the data from the map, you need to use `get()` method like in the example above.

However, for element `body` you will have to do a little bit more. `body` element will be treated as `HashMap<String, String>`, so to get element from `body` like `type`, you have to do the following:

```
@Test(dataProvider = "body")
    public void test(HashMap<String, Object> map)
    {
        HashMap<String, String> body = map.get("body");
        String bodyType = body.get("type");
    }
```

Hope it helps!